# DataGrid, get index of a row where a column has a specific value

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagridview, datagrid

Using a WPF DataGrid, I would like to retrieve the row index of a row where a specific cell has a specific value.

In WinForms and with a DataGridView, I would do a LINQ query:

```
public int GetIndexFromDGVValue(int SearchForThis)
{
    return (dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                           .Where(r => (int)r.Cells[0].Value == SearchForThis)
                           .Select(r => r.Index)).First();
}
```

I've tried doing something similar in WPF,

```
public int GetIndexFromDataGridValue(int SearchForThis)
{
    return (dg.Items.Cast<DataGridRow>()
                           .Where(r => (int)r[0] == SearchForThis)
                           .Select(r => r.Index)).First();
}
```

However, I can't do this, because DataGridRow doesn't accept an index.

Comment: Is you dataGrid binded to some object?

Comment: No. I'm adding Rows manually.

Comment: In WPF you would typically bind the DataGrid to an ItemsSource, which is a collection of objects. The collection is typically an ObservableCollection<Of your type that you want to see in the grid>. You could then run your linq query against that collection.

Comment: Right, I'm binding the DataGrid to a DataTable. Makes things easier too.